# How to sketch $f(z) = \frac{1}{64}i \times z$ on the complex plane?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, visualization

How do I sketch a plane of points on the complex plane that is multiplied by $\frac{1}{64}i$? I mean $f(z) = \frac{1}{64}i\times z$. Do I just rotate my existing plane by $\frac{1}{64}\times\frac{\pi}{2}$ to the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You rotate (clockwise) by an angle $\frac\pi2$, and then you apply a contraction centered at the origin in which everything is reduced by a factor of $64$.

Comment: Ok, so I rotate everyting and then make it smaller (multiply all modulos by 1/64)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.